# How can I start a Hangouts phone call with Applescript/Terminal?

Tags: applescript, automation, google

I want to initiate a Google Hangouts phone call with Applescript.

Hangouts has an AS dictionary, but with only the default suites.

I want to emulate opening the Hangouts popup, typing in a phone number, and starting the call.

I looked at [Hangouts API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/), but it is beyond me. But I think it could be done by calling python or ruby scripts from Terminal.

(I would like to integrate this into [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/)'s action-on-phone-number feature.)

Comment: Hangouts has an AppleScript dictionary?

Comment: Exactly what I though?  @Ze've what app are you using??

Comment: Just shift-cmd-O from AS editor... But nothing inside of it.

Comment: @Ze'ev Did you ever find a good solution to this question?

Answer (score 1):

This script I wrote works for me.  You may need to adjust a few of the delay values, depending on the speed in which your computer launches your browser etc.

I actually wrote this script and saved it as an application and then I enabled it as a dictation command

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set URL of document 1 to "https://hangouts.google.com/"
    delay 8 --adjust this value if needed
    set the clipboard to "1-234-567-8910" -- enter the real phone number
    tell application "System Events"
        click button 5 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Google Hangouts" of application process "Safari"
        delay 1
        click button "New conversation" of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 11 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Google Hangouts" of application process "Safari"
        keystroke (the clipboard)
        delay 2
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: As of 2017_01_28, this code does not work. If you can fix the issue, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @rubik'ssphere thank you for pointing out my original script no longer worked.  I made some adjustments to the original and now the script works again

Comment: The new code works perfectly. My web browser of choice is actually Google Chrome. Can you write a version of this code for Chrome? What about for the desktop Google Hangouts.app?

Comment: @rubik'ssphere my first attempt was with Google Chrome and I could not get it to work. I even tried adding a JavaScript command for the action of clicking on the "new conversation" button in Google Chrome. When I tried compiling the script, in script editor, it kept throwing an error message "access to blah blah blah… denied"